# Undefined reference A::A

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors

This is just a simple example of a bigger problem.
I have the header-file a.h with the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    A(int b);
}
```

And the source-file a.cpp with the following code:

```
#include "a.h"
A::A(int b){
    (*this).a = b;
}
```

Also a main.cpp file which creates an instance of the class:

```
#include "a.h"
int main () {
    A *test = new A(5);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling now on Ubuntu with g++ (5.4) with the following command:

> g++ -o main main.cpp

So the problem is now that I get an Error from the Linker which says:

> test.cpp:(.text+0x21): Undefined reference to function `A::A(int)'

All the files are in the same destination.
So what is the solution here?
If I include the a.cpp file in the main.cpp the linker doesn't throw any error. But that should't be the solution.

Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: `g++ -o main a.cpp main.cpp`

Comment: Thanks now it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix